# When running external commands in Mathematica, how to use external and internal variables simultaneously

Tags: bash, wolfram-mathematica

I'd like to extract texts in Mathematica on a linux server.

```
Import["!grep 'keyword' filename","Text"]
```

works. However, ideally I'd like to make it a function then the filename would be read as a Mathematica internal variable rather than typing it directly. I suppose it'll look something like this

```
f[filename_]:=Import["!grep 'keyword' filename","Text"]
```

I worked on quotes and spaces for a while and couldn't figure it out. Other solutions for commands like

```
<<!grep...
```

or RunThrough will be helpful too.

Comment: Do you mean like `f[filename_]:=Import["!grep 'keyword' "<>ToString[filename],"Text"]` (untested)?

Answer (score 1):

The `filename` parameter should be a String.  Converting an expression to a String is not robust as it will be parsed first and spaces may be added or lost, among other changes, even if the function is given the attribute `HoldAllComplete`.  Instead use:

```
f[filename_String] := Import["!grep 'keyword' " <> filename, "Text"]
```

Then:

```
f["file.txt"]
```

---

Try asking your future questions on the proper Stack Exchange site:

[image]